# Error While installing packages in pycharm i.e pandas and all

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I have just installed pycharm 2019 edition. I have already installed python 3.7 in my system. My normal python program in pycharm is running fine i.e. printing hello world but I am not able to install packages like pandas and all. its showing error. 2nd thing i am not able to see latest version of pip that is been shown in pycharm.

I have tried to do this with some changes in manage repositories but It didn't wokred

While clicking on pip its showing "Error loading package list:pypi.python.org" this error message.

I want to install packages but cant able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Please download Anaconda Distribution, which is basically made for pandas and all. You can use Spyder which is one of the best tools for Data Science. There you can easily install pandas.